# PHP Checking if user is online

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp

I don't fully understand the PHP time functions, but I'm under the impression my function should work:

```
function user_status($timestamp){
        $online = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-5 minutes', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))));
        $away = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-15 minutes', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))));
        $offline = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-30 minutes', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))));

        if(strtotime($timestamp) >= $online){
            return 'online';
        } else if(strtotime($timestamp) >= $away){
            return 'away';
        } else {
            return 'offline';
        }
    }
```

It always returns online when I am passing the timestamp of when the user was last active. What's the problem here? Am I just formatting the status variable times incorrectly?

Comment: you function is basically cargo-cult programming. `date()` takes a timestamp and formats it to a string. `strtotime()` takes a string and turns it into a atimestamp. so `strtotime(date('...'))` is basically just a massively inefficient `time()`.

Comment: Hint: Look at what `$online` actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to admit the date/time functions in PHP are a bit cumbersome. That is the reason I always work with the [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) toolbox when working with dates and times. And if you are using composer, including it is as easy as typing `composer require nesbot/carbon` in your console.

It is not only very complete and easy to use, it just makes your code that much more readable. Your code, using Carbon, would look something like this:

```
function user_status($timestamp){
    $lastAction = Carbon::createFromTimeStamp($timestamp);
    $minutesIdle = $lastAction->diffInMinutes(Carbon::now());

    if ($minutesIdle > 30) {
         return 'offline';
    } else if ($minutesIdle > 15) {
         return 'away';
    } else {
         return 'online';
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the code, but I believe it should do the trick.

That being said, your code shouldn't be that hard to get to work either.

- Remove that parsing of dates, and stick to timestamps (which is basically the number of seconds since the epoch, in case you didn't know).
- Start with your biggest interval and work your way down, or you'll indeed always get 'online' as an answer (30 > 15 > 5).
- that last interval, $offline, isn't even needed, you don't use it anyway.

The code would look something like this:

```
function user_status($timestamp){
    $now = time();
    $online = $now - 5*60;
    $away = $now - 15*60;
    // just for readability, you could also do $online = time() - 300; and so on

    if($timestamp <= $away){
        return 'offline';
    } else if($timestamp <= $online){
        return 'away';
    } else {
        return 'online';
    }
}
```